# Understanding a problem and the construction of a proof

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, strong-convergence

Hello Math Stack Exchange. I'm currectly studying the functional analysis, and I am kind of rusty to construct a proof. I have been thinking a lot about the problem, that I have been unsure how to understand in the hint. Here is what the problem says:

> **Problem A**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be infinite dimensional Banach spaces. If $X$ is reflexive and separable, and $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ satisfies that $\| Tx_n - Tx\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ whenever $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence in $X$ converging weakly to $x\in X$, then $T\in \mathcal{K}(X,Y)$.

Then, the hint says,

> Suppose that $T$ is not compact. Show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in the unit ball of $X$ such that $\| Tx_n - Tx_m\|\geq \epsilon$ for all $n\neq m$. Then show that $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ has a weakly convergent sequence.

**Edit2**: This is similar to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594777/completely-continuous-implies-compact), where one may put $X=E$ in the answer there. On the other hand, I'd very much like to know how to show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in the unit ball of $X$ such that $\| Tx_n - Tx_m\|\geq \epsilon$ for all $n\neq m$. I have explained what I thought in the comment below.

Comment: In  version 2 it is "let $(x_n)_n$ be $a$ sequence..." but in the 1st version it is "for $all$  $(x_n)_n$...."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I understand. My opinion is, this "a" should be understood as "any", since that sequence is not specified yet. The sequence can be anything, as long as it satisfies the weak convergence condition.

Comment: This is about terminology. In mathematical English, " Let A be such that ....."  customarily  means " There exists an A  such that ...."  rather  than "For all A such that ..." Ordinary speech was not developed for the purpose of higher math,...   except possibly German....:)

Answer (score 1):

You should proof it by contradiction as the hint suggests it. If the hint is satisfied then you have found a weakly convergent (sub-)sequent $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ for which $(T(x_{n_k}))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ isn't Cauchy, thus not convergent which contradicts your conditions.

Comment: That's what I thought about proof by contradiction (as I have mentioned in the first edit). So, one should assume $T\notin \mathcal{K}(X,Y)$ and $(Tx_n)$ is (strongly) convergent to $Tx$. Could you please show me why there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a such sequence so that a property is satisfied (in hint)? I know that, since $X$ is reflexive, the closed unit ball on $X$ is weakly compact. Letting $(y_n)_n$ to be a sequence lying in that closed ball, it ensures that $(y_n)_n$ is bounded. Then it has weakly convergent subsequence. But I can not fill the gap to what the first step in the hint says.

Comment: @AthenB -- look up what the definition of a compact operator $T$ is.  Then you'll see that to start the proof by contradiction you *have* to assume the conditions in the hint.

Comment: There is a relevant equivalence: $T$ is compact iff every bounded sequence $(y_n)\subseteq X$ there exists a subsequence of $(T(y_n))$ that converges. So, since $T$ is not compact, there exists a bounded sequence so that for each subsequence of $(T(y_n))$ does not converge, and then apply the negated definition of Cauchy definition?